# How to omit too much space of the text when refer to the chapter in \ctexset?

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, ctex

I define the style of the chapter with `\ctexset`, and it meets my requirement. But I refer to the chapter and there is too much blank between the text. For example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[UTF8,heading = true]{ctex}
\ctexset{
chapter        =
          {
            number     = {第\,\chinese{chapter}\,章},
            name       = {,    },
          }
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{hello}\label{sec:1}
哈哈哈\ref{sec:1}哈哈哈
哈哈哈
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

The red lines represent too much blank here. I need the space in the chapter but do not need the space in the text. How should I omit the space in the text when I refer the chapter?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using it wrong, `number` means what kind of representation of numbers should be, and should not include "第X章" and so on.

```tex
\documentclass{ctexart}
\ctexset{
  section = {
    number  = {\chinese{section}},
    name    = {第, 节},
  }
}

\begin{document}
\section{test}\label{test}
第\ref{test}节
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can add some space between 第 and `number`, `number` and 节？

Comment: yes, you need use `~`.

Comment: But the length of `~` not equals that of `\,`.